# d3 compound interest debt

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to create a compound interest modeling graph that, for each credit card, will allow users to modify (via slider) the amount of money they are paying each month and see that reflected in an exponential function graph -- as they increase the slider amount, where the exponential curve meets the top axis (year) sooner the debt will be paid off.

Would it be better to redraw exponential function on sliderchange or to create json for incremental amount and transition over each? I haven't seen many d3 exponential function examples.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking? Do you want to know the relative merits of creating a new path every onChange versus updating points in an existing path every onChange?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, I ended up updating the path and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is the best solution, but if I were doing it, here's how I might go about it:

My assumptions are that

1. Compound interest is calculated based on some interval (I guess monthly for credit cards)
2. The graph will show the total amount (owed) several years in the future, let's say 10 years.

Based on that, we can come up with the number of points to graph, e.g. 120 (10 years times 12 months).

Then, with a simple loop, I'd create a 120-element array of `null`s:

```
var points = [null, null, null, null, null, null.....null, null]; // 120 null's
```

Then I'd create a line generator that calculates X and Y based on the index in the array. Meaning, since the objective is to run something like this:

```
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', lineGenerator(points))// points are the array of nulls
```

then I'd create the line generator like this:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    // return a date value calculated as function of i
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    // return a compound interest "future value" as a function of i
  })
```

The point is that this way, when the user changes the params (via a slider), there's no need to rebuild the array of points (unless the number of points has to change, in which case I'd append/remove `null`s from it). Even the functions passed into the line generator's `x()` and `y()` methods don't have to change –– only the parameters (i.e. vars) that are used inside those functions to calculate the output have to change.

Comment: thanks, I was able to generate the entire data set and then update the path onchange.